# Как правильно пользоваться include для обработки внутри циклов?

Tags: php

```
include "vars.php";
include "connect.php";

$query = mysqli_select_db($link , $db_name)
         OR DIE ("Не моу выбрать базу, либо она отсутствует");

$result = mysqli_query($link ,  "SELECT `title` , `text` , `img` FROM `news` ");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{?>
    <div class="post">
        <h2><?= $row['title'];?></h2>
             <img src="IMG/<?= $row['img'];?>" title="" />
            <p><?= $row['text'];?></p>
    </div>
<?}?>
```

хотелось бы убрать / скрыть или перенести в другой файл именно вот это :

```
$query = mysqli_select_db($link , $db_name)
         OR DIE ("Не могу выбрать базу, либо она отсутствует");

$result = mysqli_query($link , "SELECT `title`, `text`, `img` FROM `news`");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

т.е оставить только :

```
include "vars.php";
include "connect.php";

{?>
    <div class="post">
        <h2><?= $row['title'];?></h2>
             <img src="IMG/<?= $row['img'];?>" title="" />
            <p><?= $row['text'];?></p>
    </div>
<?}?>
```

как это можно реализовать , правильно ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут `include` вряд ли стоит использовать непосредственно, разве что для хранения удобной функции-обработчика, которая в цикле вызывает функцию обратного вызова. Например, вы можете вынести этот фрагмент в функцию, например `cursor()`, и поместить ее в одноименный файл cursor.php

```
<?php
function cursor($link, $query, $callback)
{
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $callback($row);
  }
}
```

Функция `cursor()` принимает в качестве аргумента функцию обратного вызова, в которую можно помещать обработку результирующей таблицы. В вашем случае целевом файл может выглядеть следующим образом

```
<?php
include_once "vars.php";
include_once "connect.php";
include_once "cursor.php";

$query = "SELECT `title`, `text`, `img` FROM `news`";
cursor($link, $query, function($row) {
  ?>
    <div class="post">
        <h2><?= $row['title'];?></h2>
             <img src="IMG/<?= $row['img'];?>" title="" />
            <p><?= $row['text'];?></p>
    </div>
  <?
});
```

Comment: ошибок километр вывалило

Comment: Можете привести сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in Z:\home\site.tab.ru\www\index.php on line 53   на 53 </body>

Comment: После }); последнего файла есть закрывающий тэг ?> ? Если нет, добавьте пожалуйста

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 4 for cursor(), called in Z:\home\site.tab.ru\www\index.php on line 50 and defined in Z:\home\site.tab.ru\www\cursor.php on line 2
Не моу выбрать базу, либо она отсутствует

Comment: Мы немного с Ипатьевым поправили ответ, теперь функция содержит три аргумента - возьмите пожалуйста новый вариант. Кроме того, обратите внимание на фрагмент $query = mysqli_select_db($link , $db_name) OR DIE ("Не могу выбрать базу, либо она отсутствует"); Его лучше вынести в файл connect.php.

Comment: как 1000 раз поставить лучший ответ ???

Comment: Лучше не стоит - SO откатывает такие попытки :) Рад, что вам помог мой ответ.

Comment: ВООБЩЕ НИГДЕ НЕ НАДО писать mysqli_select_db

Comment: в смысле не надо ?

Comment: @LenovoID потому что ты уже выбрал БД в mysqli_connect

Comment: а точно точно , офигеть а я прошляпил это , спасибо , полезное замечание

Comment: @cheops, зря вы предлагаете смешивать логику с представлением неокрепшим умам новичков. Ну и за SQL в шаблонах традиционно палкой по рукам (т.е. минус).

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, автор спрашивает про простую систему шаблонов.

То есть, ему надо поменять структуру файлов - выносить в отдельный файл надо не запрос данных из БД, а вывод. Таким образом у него получится примитивный контроллер и примитивный вью.

Соответственно, используя [примтивную систему шаблонов](http://phpfaq.ru/tech/tpl), в "контроллере" пишем

```
<?php
include "vars.php";
include "connect.php";

$data = [];
$result = mysqli_query($link , "SELECT `title`, `text`, `img` FROM `news`");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
$tpl = "tpl_images.php";
include "tpl_main.php";
```

А уже в tpl_images.php пишем просто

```
<?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
    <div class="post">
        <h2><?= $row['title'];?></h2>
             <img src="IMG/<?= $row['img'];?>" title="" />
            <p><?= $row['text'];?></p>
    </div>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: и вам огромное спасибо , но вопрос ни как вывести или что то ещё img а именно убрать сам while , в общем я понял что совместно с вами обладатель лучшего ответа мне донесли как это делается

Comment: Ну так я и убрал while из шаблона - что и требовалось сделать. "Лучший" ответ на самом деле перемешивает бизнес-логику и представление, засовывая вью в контроллер. Ты бы определился сначала, что тебе надо.

Comment: как я далёк от теоретической части php , и не у кого учится ,php.net шаблоны стандартные там, а вот как вы - я не могу и не умею , что бы исходя из ситуации делать что то , спасибо

Comment: Смотри, подход у тебя правильный. Но понимание неверное. Надо не от while избавляться, а разделять SQL и HTML. Тебе нужно просто соблюдать одно простое правило - не должно быть ни одного файла, в котором одновременно встречался бы и SQL и HTML код. Либо то, либо другое. И всё сразу встанет на свои места.

Comment: SQL это то что у меня в $result = mysqli_query($link , "SELECT `title`, `text`, `img` FROM `news`"); ?

Comment: Да, это SQL. Код в контроллере должен только обрабатывать данные, но не выводить их. А выводом должен заниматься шаблон. Причем, пока работает контроллер, никакого вывода не должно быть ни в коем случае. Как у тебя выводится шапка сайта?

Comment: я пока только цикл учу , с html у меня на 100% дружба ,  а вот php хромает очень сильно , очень , header вывожу статически - пока ещё

Comment: Ну вот когда поймешь, что хидер должен выводиться динамически, посмотри этот пример снова.

Comment: ты намекаешь что и его надо выводить через цикл ?

Comment: Нет, я намекаю, что хидер должен выводиться после того, как отработает контроллер. А не до.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39486/discussion-between-lenovoid-and-).

Comment: буду работать над этим - спасибо , главное что бы меня понимали , что я не гуру php - учусь в само низу